# How to yield an event periodically into schedule without waiting in SimPy?

Tags: python, simpy

I am learning SimPy. Currently I need to call a method periodically until the simulation ends.

I wrote it like

```
import SimPy.Simulation as Simpy

class mod(Simpy.Process):
    def do(self):
        print(Simpy.now(), "Do!")
        yield Simpy.hold, self, 5.0

class trigger(Simpy.Process):
    def ACTIONS(self):
        while True:
            for i in self.target.do():
                yield i
            yield Simpy.hold, self, 1.0

    def set_target(self, tar):
        self.target = tar


Simpy.initialize()
obj = mod()
tri = trigger()
tri.set_target(obj)
tri.start(at=0.0)
Simpy.simulate(until=100.0)
```

Due to the statements in the `while True:`,it should yield the `target.do()` by every 1.0 time unit. Therefore the output should be:

```
0.0 Do!
1.0 Do!
2.0 Do!
......
```

But in fact, it yield the `target.do()` by every 6.0 time unit (the `yield` holds to wait until the `target.do()` finishes):

```
0.0 Do!
6.0 Do!
12.0 Do!
```

I wonder that how can I yield the target function periodically into the schedule, without waiting until it finishes executing?

Thank you!
    ......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I figured it out by myself. A `Process` in SimPy is a kind of thing as an event. Whenever it has been scheduled and then completed, it will be terminated. Therefore whenever you want to insert an event into the timeline, the instance of `Process` should be a **new** one. In other word, the `Process` should be treated as a disposable signal, instead of the working method itself.

So, the `Process`should be like:

```
class Event(Simpy.Process):
    def call_do(self, subject):
        subject.do()
```

and the working method should no longer be a instance of `Process`. the time delay should be controlled by activating `event` instead of being controlled by workflow:

```
class mod():
    def do(self):
        print(Simpy.now(), "Do!")
```

Finally, we can schedule it like this:

```
while True:
    e = Event()
    Simpy.activate(e, e.call_do(self.target), delay = 5.0)
    yield Simpy.hold, self, 1.0
```